# Suggestions required to convert ruby 1.8.x to 4.1 version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have developed application on rails 1.8.7 three years back. Now i would like to convert it to latest version of rails.

Can you suggest steps to convert to latest version ?

Comment: `Ruby 4.1` has not developed yet.I guess you meant `Rails 4.1`.

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry. It's rails

Comment: rails 1.8.7 doesn't exist. I think you mean ruby 1.8.7, and rails 4.1, which are completely different things.

Comment: My current rails version is 1.2.5.

Comment: it is rather unlikely a rails 1.2 app can be upgraded to rails 4. At that point it would probably be better to rewrite it with the latest version of rails.

Comment: In which areas i need to concentrate when i rewrite.

Comment: Umm ... like ... every area. You do a `rails g YourAppName` with Rails 4.1 and Ruby 2.1.0 and start implementing.

Answer (score 0):

As Pavan already said, you probably mean Rails 4.1. Was your application developed with Rails 3.2? If so, check out this upgrade guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0 You should upgrade from 3.2 to 4.0 first and then use the advantages of 4.1.

Of course, a decent test coverage helps you to reduce time spent on debugging and error finding.

Also you need to upgrade your Ruby version to at least 1.9.2 (2.1.0 is better). This should not introduce any errors to your code.

edit:

If you are absolutely sure you have Rails 1.2.5, it will actually be too old to upgrade it. You need to upgrade it to every major version and see if everything is stable. I assume the effort to reimplement it in Rails 4 directly is not much larger.

Comment: No. My application is developed with rails 1.8.7.

Comment: Do you have a file named `Gemfile` in your project/application directory? If yes, you have at least Rails 3. I still don't really believe you are working with Rails 1.8.7 ;)

Comment: @SebastianWramba whilst a good rule of thumb it is possible to put bundler on a rails 2 project and therefore have a Gemfile

Comment: My current rails version is 1.2.5.

Comment: @Baloo Thanks, just saw that it was introduced in Rails 3. Good hint.

Comment: Edited my answer according to latest news.